# Can you charge a 12vdc car battery with a 18 volt tool battery charger?

Tags: batteries, charging

Can you charge a 12vdc car battery with an 18 volt tool battery charger? I'm trying to get it up to more like 14.5 or 15 vdc....I don't have any other chargers in the house at the moment.

Comment: You can certainly try, but the battery won't survive. Your house might not either.

Comment: Gotcha, well I don't want that to happen! Thank you! I figured I'd be getting these answers, just didn't know if there were any modifications I could do to make it work. Possibly with resistors and diodes? Thank you very much for your time answering my question! 

Comment: Any modifications you could make would be substantially more complicated and less trustworthy than just getting an appropriate charger.

Answer (score 2):

No. The charger won't know when to stop properly or how to monitor the cells; it will likely refuse to charge entirely. Furthermore, batteries cannot change their rated voltage by charging at a higher voltage; you're just going to create a lot of (explosive) gas and heat.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked the question! I appreciate your input!! Tytyty 